# How to access the system tray using the keyboard?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, notification-area

Is there a way I can access the system tray items using the keyboard in Windows XP?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can move the keyboard focus directly to the systray area (system notification icons) with <kbd>Win+B</kbd>.

After selecting an icon with the arrow keys, you can simulate a left-click with <kbd>Space</kbd> (or maybe <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and a right-click with <kbd>AppMenu</kbd> (context menu key) or <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd>.

N.B.  Using this method, some **Windows XP** users might not be able to *see* the 'focus' in the System Tray.  If you press <kbd>Win+B</kbd> and it appears that nothing has happened, don't be put off.  Try pressing <kbd>→</kbd> once or twice and then <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd>, and you might find it works regardless.  (By contrast, using [this](https://superuser.com/a/105785/138952) method may be more likely to let you *see* the 'focus'.  The 'active' icon should be highlighted in a rectangle formed of thin dotted lines.)

Comment: Awesome, as much as I love keyboard navigation in Windows I didn't know this. If I could upvote this twice I would.

Comment: Great shortcut. Where'd you learn about the Windows+B trick?

Comment: @Nonapeptide, I was trying to set some Win+<letter> hotkeys in a program I wrote but it would fail for some letters (including B). When I realized that those were already used by Windows, I just tried all of them (Win+A to Win+Z) :b

Comment: @efotinis: This is off subject but, assuming you are Elias Fotinis, could you update your email address on your web page: http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/index.html

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, that's me. Unfortunately, during the transition from dial-up to DSL a couple of years ago, I lost access to that site (hosted by my ISP) due to technical reasons. Last time I checked they wouldn't even delete it for me. I'll give it another shot, though.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this on Windows 11; Win+B still works, although you need to press Enter to see hidden icons :-)

Answer (score 15):

Tap the "Windows" key to open the start menu, but then press escape. You have just made the menu bar come into context for the keyboard. Now you can tab through the major areas of the menu bar, such as quickstart, toolbars and SysTray. Once tabbed into SysTray, you can use the arrow keys to select a specific icon and the menu key to simulate a right-click.

Comment: That's a neat trick

Comment: Thanks... I didn't know how to do that until about 30 seconds after I read the question. It's amazing what just clicking around will do for a person. =)

Comment: awesome ! As much as I love keyboard navigation I didn't know this. It just goes to prove that anything you can do in Windows with a mouse, you can do without a mouse.

EDIT: OK, ALMOST anything

Comment: Win+T should jump to task bar

Answer (score 2):

i create an autohotkey script that allows to activate the desired icon using right control and a number. The number depends on the order of appeareance of the icon. You could modify the source to adjust yours needs. Here is the full code with explanation [hotkey for the systray](https://superuser.com/questions/254908/hotkey-to-access-systray-apps-win7)