# Dismissing systray balloons with the keyboard?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, notification-area

This is probably a supplementary question to [how to access the systray using the keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/105773/how-to-access-the-system-tray-using-the-keyboard)...

I've read that, and done some googling (google fu lacking, or there really is no answer), but I can't find a nice quick keyboard shortcut to dismiss those info balloons that apps in the system tray choose to display every now and then. The hints for access in the linked question can't be used to close the balloon (and least when I've tried them here).

Now I know I can wait for a timeout and they'll go away but if I can just hit , that'd be fanstastic. So... anyone aware of a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not a keyboard shortcut, but if you right-click on **any** balloon that pops up, it will immediately disapear.  that way you don't have to squint and hunt around for that little 'x'! :-)

Comment: Interesting :-) However I'm a keyboard junkie so that still involves me moving hand away from keyboard. But still, useful to know!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm closest I could get was using Win+B to select the tray icons, but my notification only stays open for a few seconds, perhaps you could try and go from there? Sorry I couldn't help more!

Comment: Yeah, that's as far as I got as well... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb here and guessing that you find the baloons annoying and just don't want to show them at all.  There is a way to totally disable the baloon hints from showing up in the first place.  Follow these instructions to disable them http://www.winbookcorp.com/_technote/WBTA20000902.htm.  If that's not what you want sorry.

Comment: Some of them I find annoying. Some are useful. If I could selectively disable on a per-app basis, that'd go some way to relieving the burden...

Comment: Well, as far as I know there is no way to do that, good luck though.

Answer (score 1):

This AutoHotkey command should do the trick (I assigned it to Win+Shift+B):

```
; Close system tray balloon notification
#+b::SendMessage 0x41c, , , , ahk_class tooltips_class32 ;TTM_POP=0x41c
```