# Navigate to taskbar notification area using keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access the system tray using the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/105773/how-to-access-the-system-tray-using-the-keyboard)

Is there a keyboard shortcut that moves focus to the taskbar notification area?

Comment: Answered here http://superuser.com/questions/105773/how-to-access-the-system-tray-using-the-keyboard

Comment: Also, it's proper name is the `taskbar notification area`, which may help with searching in the future.

Comment: @dsolimano Thank you.  I've edited the question to reflect that.