# Start Win7 systray focus on the left?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

Prior to Windows 7 the system tray started focus from the left: <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

Windows 7 adds <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> as an alternative, but starts focus from the right.

Is there a way to change it to start focus on the left?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting left and right mixed up?  It started focus from the left in both cases over here.  I never figured out how to access the system tray using only the keyboard before, so thanks for that.

Comment: Positive about left/right. Been doing it that way for 15 years.

Comment: OK, it must be a plugin or setting. Probably Classic Shell.

Comment: @BrianTkatch - It also starts focus on the left for me, on the small `Show Hidden Icons` up-arrow (I'm not using Classic). Note: Win-B has [apparently been around since XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key) - also mentioned in [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/105773/how-to-access-the-system-tray-using-the-keyboard)

Comment: Win-B does not work on my home XP box. I appreciate the confirmation for the focus start. It must be something on my end. I don't seem to be able to close this thread without someone answering first.

Comment: Small nit: The "system tray" in Windows is actually called the "(Taskbar) Notification Area" and has been since Windows 95. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511448.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx

Comment: Everyone called it system tray back then because of systray.exe. Noone cared what the "official" name was. Indeed, calling it the "notification area" would likely have caused nothing but confusion.

Comment: Yes, I know why people call it the system tray. But systray.exe is not the "system tray" either. I'm done, I have no comments that are relevant to this question.

Comment: heh. "systray" and "system tray", regardless of correctness, are likely the most recognized terms, however. :)

Comment: @BrianTkatch if it's an issue at your end, post an answer explaining what it was & how you fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After verification, the problem was to be at my end. It is most likely the Classic Shell plugin, and i will have to pursue a fix there.

Thanx everyone for verifying. It set me on the right track!