# Weird icons near the clock in Windows

Tags: windows-10, icons

I have these icons but am not sure what they are. The green items hide whenever I hover the mouse over them. Are they a virus or something similar?

[image: Weird green icons.]

Comment: What's the name of this icon. Please elaborate. :/

Comment: I dont know they disappear when I move the mouse over them

Comment: Rather than mouse hover, you might be able to find out about them using keyboard navigation http://superuser.com/questions/105773/how-to-access-the-system-tray-using-the-keyboard

Comment: It's not that they're hiding, but whatever application on your machine with that icon is running and crashing often, without cleaning up the systray icon you see there.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Task Manager** and search for the programme with same icon. Then you can know what is it. You can also take further required action from there.

**Note:** Update your question with the detail you get in the **Task Manager**.

**Doubt:** The icon looks like that of any *Download Manager* but so many icons point towards some VIRUS.

Comment: There is no program with the same icon.

Comment: @gunescelil  Have you checked the background processes and services?

Comment: Also check for the programs which automatically start on window startup. You might find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this set of approach. As what I've seen it seems a virus - `worm` .

1. Open Task Manager - `ctrl` + `alt` + `delete` or right click the `taskbar` and select `Task Manager` -  go to **START UP** tab`

`Note: Once you found the file, you can custom scan ONLY your drive C: using your Anti-Virus` or you use [MS Safety Scanner](https://www.microsoft.com/security/scanner/en-au/default.aspx) .

**`If that program appears here, DISABLE it and right click and open it's file location - DELETE THAT ONE (Check the folder first maybe it has uninstall.exe). After that try to check your programs from`Control Panel`->`Program Features`and uninstall.`**

[image: Pic]

2. Try this one if first does not work. You just cannot open and customize your `System Tray` unlike from windows 7 - 8.1 you can. Go to `Settings` -> `Personalization` -> `TaskBar`.

[image: Pic2]

Now for this one -> `On` to display the icons -> if that appears right click that one -> Open file location if it's available.

[image: Pic3]

3. This is another approach, once you know the name of that program.
   Search the `run.exe` or simply `windows logo` + `r` -> and type `msconfig`

[image: pic5]

Search for the application and stop that one under `Services` tab.
[image: pic6]

Inform us with the progress, or some of the methods work. If success will proceed from the `registry`.